# Swift Emailer rare behaviour

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, swiftmailer

I have an application developed in Symfony 2. I have a contact form in a bundle that send me a email. It works with this code.

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
->setSubject('Nueva consulta desde el formulario de contacto')
->setFrom($contacto->getEmail())
->setTo($this->container->getParameter('portada.emails.contact_email'))
->setBody($this->renderView('PortadaBundle:Page:contactoEmail.txt.twig', array('contacto' => $contacto)));

$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

And in another bundle in the same application this code NOT WORKS

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
->setSubject('Test to send emails from other bundle')
->setFrom('xxxx@yahoo.es') //mail commented
->setTo('xxxx@gmail.com')   //mail commented
->setBody('Hello');

$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

I don't understand what is happening. It is so rare ...
I checked the manual but all seems correct http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/email/email.html

I added the second parameter to send method ->send($message, $failures); but it returns me an array with zero items.

Any clue?

**EDIT**:
I haved copied the second code in the first bundle and it works fine. It must be something about the bundle.

Another clue? :)

Comment: Which version are you using? Do you return a response object after `$this->get('mailer')->send($message);`?

Comment: Symfony 2.1. Yes, I get this response '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony 2.1 needs to return a [response](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#response) to send the messages in memory. You can return for example a `redirect`, a `render` or a `forward`.

If this is not the problem, try to flush the spool in the controller to force sending the email. It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643027/swiftmailer-remove-attachment-after-send)

Comment: Yes, it is your first option. It needs to redirect, render or forward ...Thanks!!