# The correct way to attach a file to an email from a form in Symfony

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I have a form with a file upload, and I want to send the contents to an email recipient without saving the information. Currently I'm doing the following:

```
        if ($applyForm->isValid()) {

            $data = $applyForm->getData();
            $file = $applyForm['file']->getData();
            $file->move('file', $file->getClientOriginalName());

            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject('Hello')
                    ->setFrom('someone@somehwhere.com')
                    ->setTo('someoneelse@somewhere.com')
                    ->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath('file/'.$file->getClientOriginalName()))
                    ->setBody(
                        $this->renderView(
                            'WebBundle:Email:apply.txt.twig', array(
                                'firstName' => $data['firstName'],
                                'lastName' => $data['lastName'],
                                'email' => $data['email'],
                                'phoneNumber' => $data['phoneNumber'],
                                'comments' => $data['comments']
                        )
                    )
                ;
                $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

                unlink('file/'.$file->getClientOriginalName());

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('Job_Detail', array(
                    'slug' => $job->getSlug(),
                    'id' => $job->getId(),
                    'status' => 'success',
                )));

        }
```

This code will only work if the unlink line is commented out. Is there a way of achieving this without saving the file somewhere?

Comment: I've just found this solution, which does fix the problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643027/swiftmailer-remove-attachment-after-send?rq=1

Comment: But it still doesn't seem right, that you have to save a file before you can attach it to an email, and then delete it afterwards

Comment: It seems right for me, this may be due to a limitation of Swiftmailer that requires the file to be readable from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftMailer doest not send the email immediately for best performance, keeps emails in the memory or files so if the email still alive in memory or file, you shouldn't delete any attachment, you can easly solve that problem with setting up a cron activity with a simple php script with this:

```
$files = glob('path/to/files/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file)
{ 
    if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); // delete file
}
```